# Who can help, why the redirect does't work when the product is added to the cart?

Tags: magento2, redirect, event-observer

Redirecttohome.php

```
namespace namespace\modul\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class RedirectToHome implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface

{

    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_storetManager;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storetManager

    ) {

        $this->_storetManager = $storetManager;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

using the checkout_cart_add_product_complete event

Comment: What do you follow to write this `$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);`?

Comment: Magento\Framework\Event\Observer

Comment: Which magento core code did you follow to write that? Usually i do redirect with `$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create(); $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart'); return $resultRedirect;` where $this->resultRedirectFactory is a Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to Redirect to Home page.

```
<?php
namespace namespace\modul\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class RedirectToHome implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_storetManager;

    protected $resultRedirect;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storetManager,
        ResultFactory $result
    ){
        $this->_storetManager = $storetManager;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //$redirectUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        //$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```